# Remove stubborn default value in DateTime text box in partial view - Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a partial view with some controls in it. One of them is a textbox that is used to enter a `DateTime` value in it. The datetime textbox is `readonly`, and the type attribute is `text` (to prevent the browser date selector popup from being shown). The DateTime property in the model class in not nulable and unique. It cannot be `nullable`.

Since the textbox is read only, the DateTime value is entered using the jQuery Datepicker with the timepicker addon, by clicking in the textbox and selecting the relevant date in datepicker popup.

Important: Although the partial view is embedded in the normal view, it is not rendered in it. The partial view, which is actually a form, is displayed in a jQuery modal when the user clicks an action link on the normal view. The partial view is embedded as an Html.Action method.

Everything works as it should. My problem is, however, when the partial view is shown in the jQuery modal, the DateTime text box is shown with the placeholder text `Monday 01, January, 0001`.

On other pages in the application with DateTime controls in them, all I needed to do was change the type attribute to “text” and add an HTML placeholder by `@placeholder ="Select date"`, But this did not work.

Any assistance would be appreciated

**Edited the title** : Changed "placeholder" to "default value"

Model

```
    [Index(IsUnique = true)] 
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd dd, MMMM, yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Record Date")]
    public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    //[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateNewRecordOnPopup([Bind(Include = "RecordID,RecordDate,TeamPeriodID,TeamOnDutyID")] Record record)
    {
        ViewBag.TeamOnDutyID = new SelectList(db.TeamOnDutys, "TeamOnDutyID", "Name");

        ViewBag.TeamPeriodId = new SelectList(db.TeamPeriods, "TeamPeriodID", "Name");
        return PartialView("_CreateNewRecordOnPopupPV", record);
    }
```

Partial View in Normal View

`@Html.Action("CreateNewRecordOnPopup", "Records")`

Partial View

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecordDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @type = "text", placeholder = "Select date" } })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `DateTime` property is non-nullable, so it comes with a default value of `default(DateTime)`, which is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. It's not a placeholder. It's literally the initial value because it has to be set to *something*.

To get rid of this, make your `DateTime` nullable, i.e. `DateTime?`. You can still enforce that it be set to something by decorating it with `[Required]` if you need to. However, since it's nullable, it's default value will be null or an empty string in the input.

Comment: Hi. When the textbox control is rendered on a normal view it is not displayed and any placeholder can be used using placeholder = "Select date" } }). But in the partial view it does not work.

Comment: Again, this isn't a placeholder. It's *the actual value of the property*. I'm not sure why you wouldn't have experienced this in other scenarios, but what I've told you here is definitely your problem, and the solution I gave is definitely the way to solve it.

Comment: Your answer did solve the problem but the validation text was always shown, so I had to clear it by calling the ModelState.Clear() in the partial view controller. Thank you.